# Android storage , where did my 2GB go?

Tags: insufficient-memory, partitions

I have an Android phone and trying to understand how it deals with disk space. When I connect my phone to my computer via USB, I can see that I have:
* internal storage space (1.8GB)
* SD card (16GB)

My android phone still complains often that I don't have enough free storage. So I installed the DiskUsage app (which was suggested on some blog). It visualizes perfectly how the data is organized. The app shows that I have roughly 700MB of total storage. Why is that? According to Windows I still have 1.7GB free.

[image: Displayed in Windows]

How does this work? Does Android run on a partition which only is 700MB? How can I access the "other" 1.8 GB?? Is there a way to reclaim all that unavailable storage space?

[image: Displayed in Disk Usage App]

Comment: While in that Disk Usage app, click the back button. You should get more options than just the `Data` partition?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot with 700MB of total storage?

Comment: @Alex.S that might not be relevant. The [insufficient storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) broadcast is triggered only for the `/data` partition (usually when free space falls below 10%).

Comment: @Fiksdal that's correct. I thought it shows my SD card as additional card (so not the same physical storage device with the remaining 1.7ishGB). I will check though, thx

Comment: @bas Alright, let us know what you find.

Comment: @Fiksdal, the two partitions shown are "storage card" (the 700MB one, and 2GB when I plug the phone in my computer) and "SDcard" (the sdcard, which has all available storage as it should. So it still seems I've lost 1,3GB of storage on my phone to something. Is it possible that the producer partitioned the storage card and reserved the 1.3GB? If so, is there a way to repartition the storage card to reclaim what's rightfully mine? :)

Comment: @bas First of all, what does [this screen](http://imgur.com/9FaZwXD) look like on your device?

Comment: @Fiksdal, I added a picture to the question. It's from my own phone though, (the quesetion/problem is on the phone of my father), but it's the exact same list of storage devices (except that my device is rooted, my fathers isn't). Two found storage devices, phone storage + SD card. On my phone I can see that the disk storage shown in Android is equal to the storage I see in Windows. On my fathers phone it remains the same issue I stated before: 750ish MB in Android, 2GB in Windows. I hope you can make sense out of this.

Comment: @bas SD card refers to a removable SD? The diagram below is of "storage card"?

Comment: @Fiksdal, yes that's correct. The storage card is the 750MB part, while its showing 2gb in windows connected through usb

Comment: @bas What happens if you try to copy a 1 GB file to the storage through Windows?

Comment: @Fiksdal I will give that a try, I will get back here when I visited my parents,might take a few days though

Comment: @bas Alright, sure :)

Comment: @Fiksdal, Aha, you couldn't have been more right. I lied, the overview of partitions is not equal to what I have. There in fact are three partitions listed in DiskUsage start screen: 1) apps memory, 2) phone memory, 3) SD card. The confusing part was that windows only shown 2 and 3, which pushed me on the wrong track. So the problem is the default partitioning of the phone. I guess the only way forward is rooting it and repartitioning it (or throw the old piece of junk in the garbage can and buy something new :). Any way, thx a bunch for your time and advise!!

Comment: @bas Sure, happy to help :) I typed it into a proper answer for the benefit of other people with the same problem.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the one screenshot from OP? It's from another device, right?

Comment: @Fiksdal yeah good one! Thx again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal SD-card of the device is probably partitioned.

Check out this screen in the app you mention in OP:

[image: DiskUsage screenshot]

Since my SD-card is not partitioned, I only see one partition. In your case, you should see more than one. The combined sum of all the partitions should equal the total size of the SD-card.

You could root the device and attempt to change the partition table and merge the partitions. It may be a bit risky, though. But it's certainly worth trying if you're open to the risk of rooting, tinkering, etc.

You may also try apps such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) to move apps to the storage partition. You can free up space on the app partition that way.

If you want to root, you can also use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp) to remove bloatware system apps that you don't need. This can also free up space. However, this may also be risky. If you try this, you should be prepared that something might potentially go wrong, and you might have to re-flash stock firmware. That said, removing preloaded bloatware is often easy and trouble-free.